# ul elements coming out in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, css-float

I tried to do a sticky navigation bar so i have given `position:fixed` for the main navigation div and i added `position:relative` to its child elements which are `ul li`. why am giving `relative` means i want some space in left side so i have give `position:relative` with `left:20%`.

I got some spaces but the elements are flowing out of the navigation box.

**HTML**

```
 <nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">one</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">two</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">four</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigation{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    left:0;
    background-color: black;
}
ul{
     position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
     position: relative;
    width:20%;
    left: 20%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 0 2px 0 0;
    border-color:white;
    border-style: solid;

}

nav#navigation ul li:last-child{
    border: none;
}
nav#navigation ul li:hover{
    background-color: grey;
}
nav#navigation ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
body{
    background-color:pink;
}
```

I think its problem with `position:relative`. can anybody give a explain of what happening and what can be done.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt7NL/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `height:60px;` and `line-height` on `#navigation` which is preventing the `height` to exceed more than `60px` as well as the `line-height` bloats the `height` of your menu even if you will get rid of the `height` property, also you need to `clear` your `float` as well...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt7NL/4/)

For now, I've added `overflow: hidden;` on the `ul` element, but it's better to use a self clear `class` to `clear`

```
.clear:after {
   clear: both;
   display: table;
   content: "";
}
```

And use this `class` on your `ul` element, and you can get rid of `overflow: hidden;` ...

---

As you commented, you are not normalizing your CSS, you need reset the `margin` of the `ul` element, so use `margin: 0;` on the `ul`.

Also, always, reset the browser default CSS by using [Normalizing Stylesheets](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or simply use

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt7NL/7/) OR [**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt7NL/10/)

Comment: Thanks. I thought giving 60px in `#navigation` and `line-height:60px` in `li` will make the `li` exactly fit into the navigation bar without any margins(spaces in top and bottom).Now only i came to know the height is making a cause here.

Comment: @sun You welcome :) and don't assign `height`, keep it auto, bloat the items using `padding` if you want to

Comment: thanks +1. Can the spaces removed, it should exactly fit into navigation with border touching the end of the navigation as @Noob did.

Comment: @sun that's nothing but browsers default margin and padding http://jsfiddle.net/Wt7NL/7/ so normalize your CSS else use `margin: 0;` on `ul` element

Comment: Thank. Demo 3 was my expectation. So what the trick only remove height in #navigation and giving default margin,padding to 0 will solve the problem?

Comment: Because @NoobEditor saying line-height was the problem here. But in the demo3 its still there and works fine. Any suggestion please

Comment: @sun `line-height` is not the issue, resetting is the issue :) read my edit carefully

Answer (score 2):

See, in you fiddle    `line-height: 60px;` is causing the `li` to have a margin from the top....it has got nothing to do with `position:relative`

To counter the effect, i suggest you use `margin-top:-20px;`, Also, as Mr.Alien said, clear your floats too

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt7NL/5/)

**EDIT**

If you remove `height` and align the `line-height` to `a` tag, it'll solve all your problems:

[**see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt7NL/9/)

```
ul li > a {
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #00F;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks +1. I see a bit black space at the bottom. should we have to give margin-top:2px;

Comment: You shouldn't be using `margin-top: -20px;`

Comment: @sun : as mentioned in the edit....give `line height` to `a` tags, they are always better way to achieve the spacing,also, without the `height`, it would do well as `line-height` will do the needfull replacement of the `height` (*since they both had 60px value *)!!

Comment: LOL, I would have certainly upvoted if you didn't suggested the negative margin solution, it's kinda amateur way to do it... :) I often upvote your answers where you are correct..

Comment: Enjoy your +10 Rep :) but be sure next time you have amazing solutions first :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43971/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-mr-alien)

Comment: @NoobEditor giving line-height in a tag is good. From there i can increase the height too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just remove    line-height: 60px;

```
ul li {
    float: left;
     position: relative;
    width:20%;
    left: 20%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 0 2px 0 0;
    border-color:white;
    border-style: solid;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer:

```
ul{
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
 }
```

It is the margin that needs fixed!